# Email is not getting send from Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am sending emails from ET but it is not getting delivered to email(gmail). I have checked my spam folder also but no luck.
In tracking it is showing delivered for all the contacts.
is there any specific permission which I need to check for sending email?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and found that the problem for my org was that the marketing cloud email address had to be added to the safe sender list at the organization level by IT. Our organization uses Microsoft Outlook via Office365. I have had no problems with Gmail. I do have concerns though that other email recipients who are on Outlook clients are also showing delivered and are not receiving the emails.

Answer (score 0):

If it is listed as delivered, then Exact Target is not the issue as it sent the email correctly, it is something to do with your email client. ET will not list any email as delivered unless the receiving server has accepted it.

For example, It is possible for your email client to take DAYS to place the email into your inbox after Exact target or any sending service has delivered the email. It is not the norm, but for many different reasons the final delivery to your inbox can be delayed for extended periods. This is true for all email servers. (ref - http://ask-leo.com/how_long_should_email_take_to_be_delivered.html)

Comment: I have checked for two email client (outlook and gmail) and for both it was not delivered but in et it is showing as delivered

Comment: Well, I would check to see that your email does not contain any invalid formatting/code as well as check to see how it rates on a spam filter.  Even if it makes it through the server filter, each client has a second filter that runs before it hits your inbox. Free spam checker:  http://www.emailspamtest.com/ but if you are going to be doing a lot of emails, I would recommend a paid subscription for EmailonAcid or Litmus. Exact Target also has options in it (content detective) that can help.

Comment: @Gortonington your two email clients, are they both using the same gmail inbox? Try two different inboxes if so.